# TinyMCE inline editor will not appear / classic menu will not work

Tags: jquery, tinymce, inline

[image]

I am having a problem with TinyMCE being used in conjunction with jQuery.

I have included TinyMCE from the CDN:-

```
<script src="//cdn.tinymce.com/4/tinymce.min.js"></script>
```

I've then init'd the editor on an editable Div with an ID of detailedDescriptionCapture.

This was the inline code I tried:-

```
      tinymce.init({
      selector: 'div#detailedDescriptionCapture',
      inline: true,
      plugins: [
        'advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor',
        'searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen',
        'insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste'
      ],
      toolbar: 'insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image'

});
```

No editor appeared. When I tried the classic init, non-inline, the editor appeared but none of the function dropdowns appear when clicked such as formats, font sizes, the insert menu (when that is included in the init) etc.

Does anyone have an idea as to what might be causing this? If I click code for example, no overlay appears.

Comment: can you provide full code? Because the code you provided works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, nevermind this is just a straightforward z-index issue.